# Подскажите как на базовом уровне знаний удалить слова начинающиеся на гласную букву в LInkedList в Java

Tags: java, коллекции, linked-list

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу: Создайте класс Animal, где поле name, - название животного. Добавьте 10 животных в LinkedList, удалите те объекты, name которых начинается с гласной буквы.

Написал такой код, он вроде работает, но я так понимаю, что это как называют профессионалы говнокод. Как можно решить эту задачу проще

````
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Animal cat = new Animal("Cat");
      Animal dog = new Animal("Dog");
      Animal tiger = new Animal("Tiger");
      Animal lion = new Animal("Lion");
      Animal cow = new Animal("Cow");
      Animal sheep = new Animal("Sheep");
      Animal fox = new Animal("Fox");
      Animal woolf = new Animal("Woolf");
      Animal rat = new Animal("Rat");
      Animal Elefant = new Animal("Elefant");

      LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<>();
      
      ll.add(cat.name);
      ll.add(dog.name);
      ll.add(tiger.name);
      ll.add(lion.name);
      ll.add(cow.name);
      ll.add(sheep.name);
      ll.add(fox.name);
      ll.add(woolf.name);
      ll.add(rat.name);
      ll.add(Elefant.name);

      ll.removeIf(s -> s.startsWith("A") || s.startsWith("E") || s.startsWith("I") || s.startsWith("O")
              || s.startsWith("U") || s.startsWith("Y"));

      System.out.print(ll);



  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, в список *строк* у вас добавляются не животные, а их названия (и соответственно удаляются).

Во-вторых, инициализировать список можно проще.

В целом, идея использовать `List::removeIf` корректна, но вместо нескольких вызовов `String::startsWith` лучше использовать `String::matches`:

```java
LinkedList<Animal> animals = new LinkedList<>(
    Arrays.asList(cat, dog, tiger, lion, cow, sheep, fox, woolf, rat, Elefant)
);

// с использованием String::substring для проверки только одной буквы
animals.removeIf(a -> a.name.substring(0, 1).matches("(?i)[AEIOU]")); // y - не гласная!

// с поиском первой гласной буквы в регулярке
animals.removeIf(a -> a.name.matches("(?i)[AEIOU][a-z]+")); // y - не гласная!
```

Comment: Спасибо, а чтобы теперь правильно вывести получившийся list как прописать? Если написать ```System out print(animals)``` выдает такой ответ ```[linkedList.Animal@27d6c5e0, linkedList.Animal@4f3f5b24, linkedList.Animal@15aeb7ab, linkedList.Animal@7b23ec81, linkedList.Animal@6acbcfc0, linkedList.Animal@5f184fc6, linkedList.Animal@3feba861, linkedList.Animal@5b480cf9, linkedList.Animal@6f496d9f]
```

Comment: Для вывода списка в классе `Animal` должен быть переопределен метод `toString`: `@Override public String toString() { return "Animal: name=" + name;}`.  Можете либо распечатать весь список целиком: `System.out.println(animals);` либо построчно каждое животное: `animals.forEach(System.out::println);`